# Mimicking overleaf compiling in VS code

Tags: vscode

I'm trying to render a LaTeX PDF using both `hyperref` and `biblatex` and a `psfrag` based package (`chemscheme`), I posted a question earlier but I'm not sure what the real fix is. Now I found that using Overleaf I can get it to work (using `auto-pst-pdf`) using 'standard' PdfLaTeX as the compiler and TeX Live 2020.

I want to write my LaTeX in VS Studio so I figure if I can mimic whatever build path/recipe Overleaf uses I can get it to work, is there someone that can help me do this withing LaTeX Workshop (and/or explain me the exact difference in function of a compiler, recipe and TeX distribution)

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/yfzrcrwgpbpt) is an example of my file working in Overleaf (for some reason I had to change `.bib` to `.BIB` otherwise it's the exact code I try to run on desktop), I am interested in the `example.eps` scheme (the other figure is there to test `hyperref`, as is the random text and references for BibLaTeX).

When running from VS code if I out `pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex` in the terminal I get a PDF in which my figure is not visible.

Update: I got it to work to fix the `auto-pst-pdf` I had to follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570404/pdflatex-fails-on-pstool-when-hyperref-is-included) solution, so adding

```
\makeatletter
\ifPreview
  \let\Hy@FirstPageHook\relax
  \let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
\fi
\makeatother
```

just after `hyperref`. In all honesty I am not sure what this does, and why it's required when running PdfLaTeX on my pc and not when running it in overleaf.
To fix for the references was 'simpler' I just have run biber after my first run of PdfLaTex, and then run PdfLaTeX once more.

note: as an alternative I can run `latexmk --shell-escape -pdf main.tex` to do all that in one go. The pdf I get from this in the end looks perfectly fine, however I do still get an error that it exceeds the maximum number of runs without getting a stable file (Since the pdf looks good I am not sure what is causing this, but I can live with it)

Comment: probably `pdflatex --shell-escape file; biber file; pdflatex --shell-escape file; pdflatex --shell-escape file`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle this doesn't crash so I assume I'm using pdflatex. However it doesn't give me the same output as overleaf. I editted the question, I hope this makes it reproducible.

Comment: your file only needs to have extension `.BIB` as that is the way you reference it in the main document `\addbibresource{references.BIB}` other than that I'm not going to download all that and try locally, the code I suggest above should work so long as you have all the files locally.

Comment: vscode really isn't related here, check that you can run the commands on the commandline and get the right output, then once you know te heommands to execute getting any editor to run that sequence should be easy. If you have problems make a small self contained example to add to your question and say what error you got.

Comment: Apologies, locally all the different files were generated and I figured I'd upload as is. Removed all useless files.
The reason I mention .bib is because I have it as .bib locally, but in overleaf that doesn't work so I change the file and the \addbibresource to .BIB which fixes it.

So when I run it using the pdflatex command on my desktop I get a file in which the example.eps is not visible at all and biblatex does not seem to be working. From this I figure something is compiling differently.

Comment: it is more normal to use .bib than .BIB the only thing that matters is that the reference has to match the filename. Except if you use a case-insensitiove filename like windows .BIB does match .bib.

Comment: No sorry I am not going to download from an external site especially not download any code that requires shell-escape (doing so would give you full access to this machine, shell-escape is disabled by default for good reason) we can help but you should make an example _here_ and say what error you got.

Comment: Didn't think about that safety concern sorry. I did a bit more research and found a decent fix. Sorry for not being able to pose my question more clearly and thanks for taking the time to answer!