# auto-pst-pdf and hyperref conflict

Tags: hyperref, auto-pst-pdf

This code don't work on texlive-2021 or on Miktex (MiKTeX 21.8), with pdflatex : the auxilliary complation fail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage[cleanup={},pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNOSAFER}]{auto-pst-pdf}% 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
\psline(0,0)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
Other text

\end{document}
```

Comment: check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570832/2388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to explicit the answer that can be found following [Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615951/auto-pst-pdf-and-hyperref-conflict#comment1538604_615951), adding the following in the preamble should work (also I think `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` is currently needed in the ps2pdf step, do not comment it out).

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \let\Hy@FirstPageHook\relax
                \let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

However, it might not behave well in future versions, and is [not enough to make `[auto-]pst-pdf` work with `beamer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/617229/70966).

Comment: Thanks, it works with hyperref but unfortunatly not with bookmark