# pst-pdf and beamer conflict

Tags: beamer, preview, auto-pst-pdf

Follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615951/70966) reporting conflict between `[auto-]pst-pdf` and `hyperref`. This is apparently due to the fact that `pst-pdf` uses `preview` internally, and `preview` is currently incompatible with some `hyperref` mechanisms, as discussed along [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570404/70966) and then [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/587774/70966).

The [workaround proposed by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617227/70966) currently works for simple cases, but not when including PostScript code within frame environment of the `beamer` class.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \let\Hy@FirstPageHook\relax
                \let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
\psline(0,0)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
Other text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that only loading the beamer class does not trigger the bug, it's the frame environment that triggers it.

I am looking for a workaround that would allow me to use PStricks in beamer presentations with pdflatex from an up-to-date (2021) texlive.

Comment: it is not a direct incompability with hyperref. preview is not compatible with the new latex shipout code and hyperref is one the cases where you get problems. I have some doubts that the preview maintainer will address this in the near future. I would suggest to either use pstools + pdfcrop or to switch to lualatex. It now supports pstricks through the luapstricks package, and if you run into problems there is an active maintainer.

Comment: Many thanks for the tips. I'll first look into pstools before switching engines, which would require much more work. If pdfcrop can replace preview in pstools, do you think it could also do so in pst-pdf?

Comment: Looks like pstool does not deal with pspicture environment; it is only designed to work with psfrag, not pstricks. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Run the document with `lualatex` then you do not need `pst-pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/firstpage}[hyperref]
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[hyperref]
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[beamerbasenavigation]
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi    
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
Some text
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
\psline(0,0)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
Other text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```