# Using scrartcl with auto-pst-pdf, scrlayer-scrpage, chemnum and hyperref results in error

Tags: hyperref, miktex, koma-script, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I'm trying to write a protocol for my Masters (similar to a Bachelors Thesis) which includes chemical formulae which I am attempting to number.
My originally tried MWE was this one, it doesn't matter if the image is commented or not, it won't compile either way.
I am using TeXMaker, and for compilation I currently use the quickbuild option "LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf"

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=off,runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello World
%\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PG01.eps}
%\replacecmpd[PG01]{Alkin-1}
%\replacecmpd[PG02]{Alkin-2}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now it does work if I either

1. Comment out the hypperref package
   or
2. Change the Document-Type to "article" while still having hyperref enabled

Now the replacement of tags doesn't work either way, but I haven't really attempted to solve that yet, I at first would like my document to work before I tackle that problem.

Since I had other problems (Which I solved on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/qujny7/problem_with_generic_hook_fileaftersty_is/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))regarding the Koma-Scripts, I am using version 3.35, manually installed to MiKTex, but other than that, I am at a loss.
Before starting to write I didn't really think about it and updated all my packages, before that my basic template ran without errors.
The Error I get is the following:

```
Process started

This is dvips(k) 2020.1 (MiKTeX21.8) Copyright 2021 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)

' TeX output 2021.11.18:0829' -> MWE 2.ps

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/base/tex.pro>

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/psfrag/psfrag.pro>

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/base/texps.pro>

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/base/special.pro>.

<C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>

[1<./PG01.eps>

dvips: Could not find figure file MWE 2; continuing. ]

Process exited with error(s)
```

And I simply don't know what to do anymore. I don't even know why it is trying to figure "MWE 2" which is the name of my file, and not the name of the Image (which would be [PG01](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ugqtijgeszwdgf/PG01.eps?dl=0)).

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't use dvipdfm as driver option if you actually compile with dvips. Beside this: the preview package used by auto-pst-pdf is currently not compatible with a current latex. This has been reported but it is unclear if and when it will be fixed. Until then one has to remove various code from the hooks, e.g. for your document this should work (without the beamer specific code): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617267/2388. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/213.

Comment: And you then should use `pdflatex --shell-escape` or auto-pst-pdf wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for the informations. I should have mentioned that I have --shell-escape enabled both for pdfLaTeX and LaTeX. I have inserted the code like this [Pasebin](https://pastebin.com/2jAUpi2c) but still get the same error. Have I done something wrong there?

Comment: the code looks ok. But you added a graphic and I don't have it. Also it is a bit unclear how you compile exactly. Side remark: better remove the space from the file name, while it normally work it is in complicated workflows always a possible source for troubles.

Comment: I have the image file added in my last sentence (the Highlited PG01). I use TeXMaker to write it and have installed MiKTeX as my distribution. I then use the Quickbuild option, which, as far as I know, just executes LaTeX, then dvips and after that ps2pdf. Which should, if I am not completely wrong, work right? And holy if I remove the spaces it compiles. I will need to check it over but this may just have been about SPACES? Edit: I can confirm, if I remove the spaces from the name it compiles, even without the code you provided.

Comment: yes just saw it. With pdflatex --shell-escape your file compiles fine for me. But I don't have spaces in my file names.

Comment: if you really simply use latex + dvips, then you don't need auto-pst-pdf and the preview patches and can remove both.

Comment: Does that work? I thought I needed the auto-pst-pdf for chemnum to properly change the Placeholder Tags?

Comment: that is psfrag. auto-pst-pdf is there to allow you to use pdflatex (and so e.g. to include also png or pdf graphics) instead of latex+dvips

Comment: Ah ok yeah that makes sense. But I have one last question, since it doesn't seem to be replacing my tags when compiling with either LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf or just LaTeX + dvips. Is there something more I need to check?