# Problems with chemnum and classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, chemistry, chemnum

I'm preparing a master's thesis in organic chemistry and I wanted to use chemnum for numbering of chemical compounds on poststcript files.

The problem is that when I use classicthesis, it makes the figure disappear. Before the log resets, it produces:

```
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

And provides an empty pdf. The problem is solved when I comment out the classicthesis package. Is it possible to make both classicthesis and chemnum work?

Here's my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica, parts=false]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx,auto-pst-pdf,chemnum} 
\begin{document} 
\replacecmpd{compound1}
\replacecmpd{compound2}
\includegraphics{obrazki/exp-1.ps} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: without the image that can not be tested. Apart from this: classicthesis together with the standalone class doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem using https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/scheme-tmp.ps which is one of the example images from the Chemnum manual (and changing the documentclass to article). It works fine without the `classicthesis` package (using pdflatex with shell escape for auto-pst-pdf) but it fails when the package is used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, classicthesis is somehow incompatible with chemnum. I'm just wondering if these packages can be used together.

Comment: They can, Ulrike provided a workaround in a different question.

Comment: She has also posted an equivalent but imo a bit more readable version at https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/213.

Comment: Actually, this answer by Ulrike solved my question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617229/pst-pdf-and-beamer-conflict/617267#617267

Thank you both for your time and answers!