Apparent conflict between hyperref and auto-pst-pdf
I seem to be having a conflict between hyperref and auto-pst-pdf for generating pspictures with pdflatex.  Here's a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah

\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
\psline(0,0)(4,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}

If I compile this without the hyperref package called, it works just fine: I get text and a simple pspicture, as expected.  However, if I include the hyperref package, I get errors.  Specifically, compiling the example above with pdflatex (and -shell-escape) using TeXlive 2022 on Windows 10, I get the following error within the auto-pst-pdf part of the output:
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=latex)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 2022.1 (TeX Live 2022)  Copyright 2022 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2024.12.10:1110' -> Debugging-autopp.ps
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1]
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   --dict:13/22(ro)(L)--   1   0   0.0   -0.191512   a   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2022   1   3   %oparray_pop   2021   1   3   %oparray_pop   2009   1   3   %oparray_pop   1865   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   4   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:790/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:151/200(L)--   --dict:96/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 113758
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
system returned with code 1
PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.

==> 1 page written on `Debugging-pics.pdf'.
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"

I do get a pdf output, but it includes only the text and no pspicture.  I have the same issue if I use xelatex instead.  No issue running latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf, but that solution doesn't work for me since in my full document I need to include non-ps images.  I'd really like a solution that still works with pdflatex.
Note that I don't have the same problem on Ubuntu, so it seems specific to my Windows machine.  I've done as much digging around as I could, and it seems the Ghostscript "Unrecoverable error, exit code 1" is not uncommon, and the hyperref package causing issues is also not uncommon, but I couldn't find anything that addressed both of these issues simultaneously.  (I've tried switching the order in which I call hyperref and the pstricks packages, but that did nothing.)
Any ideas what's going on?

And of course, despite extensive Googling around before asking this question, I found a solution immediately after posting it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617227/109481.  That answer is good enough for my current purposes, but it would be nice to have a more robust resolution.

this fix is a bit more robust https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617267/2388. But a really robust solution would require an update of the preview package which takes into account the new shipout code in LaTeX.

Would switching to lualatex be an option for you?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

should we link this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617267/2388?

If anything, I'd say it's more a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615951/109481

use it this way:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\usepackage{hyperref}\fi

\begin{document}
    
    Blah blah blah
    
    \begin{pspicture}(4,4)
        \psline(0,0)(4,0)
    \end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}


This also works!  I'm not sure whether this is better than Ulrike's fix (I don't actually understand what's going on behind the scenes), but I'll mark it as an answer.
