# latex not creating .dvi, .ps files while compiling, "system returned with code 256"

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, eps, auto-pst-pdf

EDIT:
so, I found the culprit. The pdfx package is incompatible with chemstyle, but it literally comes from the template my university gave me. Fortunately, the template is from a different faculty, so I could just work around, but I actually have no idea what else to use?

I unfortunately cannot provide a MWE, as it actually works. I narrowed down the problem to the working files while compiling.
I think this is the solution but I don't understand it. https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html

I'm trying to incorperate some .eps files (necessary) into my document, using the package auto-pst-pdf.

The only difference in my MWE and my actual document is, that the MWE creates files "jobname-autopp.**aux**, jobname-autopp.**dvi**, jobname-autopp.**log**, jobname-autopp.**ps**"

while my document only creates "jobname-autopp.**log**". So the file "jobname-pics.**pdf**" is not created properly and cannot be found while compiling (using PDFlatex, texmaker, on Mac). I GUESS it has something to do with downloading the thing from overleaf (I did the same with the MWE???) but I'm also a beginner and really confused. Here's the log:

```
    
    "! Package pdftex.def Error: File "main-pics.pdf not found"
    
    "Package auto-pst-pdf Warning:
    
    Creation of main-autopp.dvi failed.
    
    This warning occured on input line 128."
    
    "Package pst-pdf Warning: File \main-pics.pdf' not found.`
    
    (pst-pdf) Use the following commands to create it:
    
    (pst-pdf) ----------------------------------------------------
    
    (pst-pdf) latex main.tex
    
    (pst-pdf) dvips -o main-pics.ps main.dvi
    
    (pst-pdf) ps2pdf main-pics.ps
    
    (pst-pdf) ---------------------------------------------------- .
```

> \RequirePackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

Comment: If your EPS files have already been made, you can just run pdflatex without auto-pst-pdf, which is for PStricks picture inclusion.

Comment: If I run it without auto-pst-pdf, the temporary placeholders in my .eps files do not get filled with actual numbers. I'm using chemnum and chemscheme for synthesis schemes, therefore I need those TMPs

Comment: without an example it is difficult to say anything definite. But pdfx loads hyperref, and hyperref is in part incompatible with the preview package used by auto-pst-pdf. You can try some of the fixes mentioned e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570832/2388

Comment: thank you, hyperref was the actual problem! 
I put in this workaround and it works finally

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \let\Hy@FirstPageHook\relax
                \let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi
}
\makeatother